# Product of Two Conditional Probabilities

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian

Suppose we have

$\Pr(A|B)\Pr(B|C) = ?$

I've tried expanding this out:

$\Pr(A|B)\Pr(B|C)=\frac{\Pr(A \cap B)}{\Pr(B)} \cdot \frac{\Pr(B \cap C)}{\Pr(C)}$

But can't seem to simplify any further. Does this simplify, or is this as nice as it gets?

My initial thought was that

$\Pr(A|B)\Pr(B|C) = \Pr(A,B|C)$

but this is wrong after simple counter example.

---

The reason I ask is I am trying to understand some of Bayesian analysis. Namely, when we integrate out the prior parameter to arrive at the posterior:

$ \int_\Omega f(x|z)f(z|y) \, dz = f(x|y)$

where I am wondering if the term under the integral will simplify to a joint density of some kind.

Comment: The expression$$\int_\Omega \Pr(A|B)\Pr(B|C) dB$$is incorrect in that $A,B,C$ are events in the lines above, not random variables and $\text{Pr}$ is the probability rather than the density.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\text{Pr}(A|B)\text{Pr}(B|C) = \text{Pr}(A,B|C)$ is true when $A \mathbin{\perp\kern-6mu\perp} C | B$ so that $\text{Pr}(A|B) = \text{Pr}(A|B,C)$.

$\mathbin{\perp\kern-6mu\perp}$ stands for (conditional) independence. So, $A \mathbin{\perp\kern-6mu\perp} C | B$ says that $A$ is conditionally independent of $C$ given $B$. Or in plain words, given the observation $B$, observing $C$ does not provide us any additional information about $A$.